# How can I stop Google searches from showing in the omnibox?

Tags: google-chrome, search, history, address-bar, omnibox

Is there a way to prevent Google searches from auto-filling in the omnibox? I used to be able to get around this by first going to Google and doing my search from there but after having to reinstall Chrome those searches are appearing even though I did not even search them from the omnibox.

I have gone into my Google account and turned off search history tracking so it seems like this is something on Chrome's end. Prediction services are disabled as well so I can't think what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to Disable "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar" by going to

1. chrome://settings
2. Show Advanced settings
3. Privacy
4. Uncheck "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar"

This should disable auto-complete when used in the URL/Search bar at the top

Comment: That's already disabled...any other tips?